# Remove ant table header for a single column

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I want to use example like this (from ant website) https://codesandbox.io/s/yw2y55?file=/demo.js:134-229,
but I need to remove what is 'Action' header here. Not just remove the word (which is easily done by leaving 'title' property empty), but I want that last column to be visible just where the data is, i.e. in data rows. Up in header, when you scroll it horizontally, I want other (scrolled) headers to be visible in place of the last header.

If I set 'display:none' in the browser inspector for the last column header, I get the desired behaviour pretty much, but how can I code this?
Ant-wise or maybe some custom css way?

Comment: Did you try removing the `fixed: 'right` property in the columns array Line 64?

Comment: @heyitsvajid I need exactly that "fixed: 'right'", but I don't want to see header above it.